# Capture a web in image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to do a practice that consists of capturing webs in jpg, but it did not just work (I am newbie), this is the code I use.

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2


def url_to_image("http://www.hereiputweb.com"):

    resp = urllib.urlopen("http://www.hereiputweb.com")
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    return image
```

The code I got it from a manual but it gives me fault in the line:

```
def url_to_image("http://www.hereiputweb.com"):
```

I think I indicated the web incorrectly, very far I should not be .. tried several forms but nothing .. what do I do wrong?

regards

Comment: def url_to_image(url="http://www.hereiputweb.com"): resp = urllib.urlopen(url) should work. Please always report the exact error you receive.

Comment: Please review this article.  I will help you get better responses when using this site.  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

There is a really brief tutorial (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).
The relevant part would be https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

So, you should define your function as follows:

```
def url_to_image(url):

    resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    return image
```

I have not checked the implementation works ;)

Then you can use your function:

```
url = "http://www.hereiputweb.com"
my_image = url_to_image(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your **implementation**, it's with your **URL**!

This method require a functioning URL that returns an image. The URL you're using is not an image.

Try using an URL of an image (e.g: some URLs that end with .jpg) and it shall work!

Remember that the URL must be on-line!

Comment: I think what the OP wants to do is taking a "screenshot" of a given website. At least is what I understand from the sentence "capturing webs in jpg".